Background operation for Flutter
I'm working on an emergency tracking app in Flutter. In case of an emergency, I need to push a button and send the location of the person to the service every 30 seconds at worst.
I use the flutter_background_service package for this. I don't have a problem on the android side, it works properly, but on the ios side the application does not work when the application is terminated. In this application, it is very important that I get the instant location of people even if the application is closed. What other way should I follow for this?

If the application is terminated, how can they tap the button, or do you mean that after they tap the button and you start send if the location stream, if the user terminates the app then the stream stops ? If so, what do you mean by "closed/terminated"? Are you referring to simply suspending the app or actually swiping it away from the app switcher?

the person thought they were going to be in a difficult situation and pressed the button and dragged the application up and closed it. At this moment, I can still track his location and show the last location to the authorized people. @paulw11

If the person swipes away the app then iOS terminates the app and assumes that the user didn't want it to run.  If the user just returns to the Home Screen then your app can get a stream of location updates in the background as long as you have "always" location permission and started updates before your app was moved to the background or you have "when in use" location permission and you started background updates before your app moved to the background.
